# nativescript - Activity restarts rather than resumes

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am an Angular developer that has been trying out Nativescript in the past couple of months. So far so good.

On the app that I am working I am experiencing a problem where the UI (the android activity) restarts after the app has been reopened from the launcher, but the background is still working (which is the behavior that I want from the background).

I have seen that this is an issue on android and its solvable. I did try to replicate the the solution in nativescript but I can't pull it through. I made a custom activity but I am facing the following error, after I reopen the application from the luncher.

```
> An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread. Unable to destroy
> activity {org.nativescript.Challanger/org.challenger.MainActivity}:
> com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onDestroy failed
> Error: View not added to this instance. View: t(2) CurrentParent:
> undefined ExpectedParent: t(1)

StackTrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {org.nativescript.Challanger/org.challenger.MainActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onDestroy failed
Error: View not added to this instance. View: t(2) CurrentParent: undefined ExpectedParent: t(1)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3945)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3963)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onDestroy failed
Error: View not added to this instance. View: t(2) CurrentParent: undefined ExpectedParent: t(1)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
    at org.challenger.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:34)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6526)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3932)
    ... 9 more
```

I did try to have use `android:launchMode="singleTask" and "singleInstance"`, but they did not help with the issue.

This is the parts of the Main activity that I use.

```
public onCreate(savedInstanceState: any): void { // android.os.Bundle
        // Set isNativeScriptActivity in onCreate (as done in the original NativeScript activity code).
        // The JS constructor might not be called because the activity is created from Android.

        this.isNativeScriptActivity = true;


        if (!this._callbacks) {
            setActivityCallbacks(this);
        }
        this._callbacks.onCreate(this, savedInstanceState, this.getIntent(), super.onCreate);

        if (!this.isTaskRoot()) {
            let intent: android.content.Intent = this.getIntent();
            let action: string = intent.getAction();
            if (intent.hasCategory(android.content.Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && action === android.content.Intent.ACTION_MAIN) {
                this.finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    }


 public onDestroy(): void {
        this._callbacks.onDestroy(this, super.onDestroy);
    }
```

How can I prevent the activity to restart? I feel that I am close, but I am missing something.

Comment: NativeScript uses one activity, all navigation happens within fragments. You don't have to do anything specifically, it's taken care by default. Can you explain why do you think it restarts instead of resume.

Comment: Hey @Manoj, tnx for the prompt respond. So my app has this feature that tracks user geolocation in the background using a notification. The tracking is activated by pressing a Start button and stopped by pressing the same button (in this case is states stop). When I put the application in the background and reopen it by using the launcher, the buttons states Start (as the initial state) but the notification and the tracking is still on. If I press start I can see that the app is making 2 subscriptions for the geolocation update. This is a problem for almost every device that I have tried.

Comment: I believe it may be a problem with your logic, as I mentioned before all Pages are fragments. The UI components will be released when app is paused and re-rendered upon resume. So only if you are updating the text property of button upon events like loaded / resume, you may encounter this issue. Please share a Playground sample if you are still not sure what's causing the issue, I might able to pin point.

Comment: Ah, l see. Does this means that Angular components are re-rendered or reinstanced ? Do you have any recommendations where I can read more on this topic?

Comment: Absolutely not, the components are not reinstated, Only the underlaying native view is. It's not possible to hit what you are saying unless you are missing something in your code so until I have a sample where the issue could be reproduced, I may not able to comment much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I had to change the page event from loaded="onLoaded" to navigatedTo="onLoaded".